# Pandas return rows with exact matches where column could have multiple values

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I am trying to find a solution to this problem:

```
import pandas as pd

i = ['7.3, 6.9.1', '7.3.1, 5.10', '6.9']

s = pd.DataFrame(i, columns=['vals'])
s[(s["vals"].apply(lambda x: '7.3' in x))]
```

The desired output here is:

```
    vals
0   7.3, 6.9.1
```

However, the output I'm getting, and I understand why, is:

```
    vals
0   7.3, 6.9.1
1   7.3.1, 5.10
```

Notice, I need to support some version of `in` as there can be multiple values in vals; however, I need to make sure I only get back the rows where there is an exact match, i.e. **7.3** not **7.3.1**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### `map` and `set.isdisjoint`

```
s[~s.vals.str.split(', ').map({'7.3'}.isdisjoint)]

         vals
0  7.3, 6.9.1
```

---

#### `split` with `expand=True` and `any(axis=1)`

```
s[s.vals.str.split(', ', expand=True).eq('7.3').any(1)]

         vals
0  7.3, 6.9.1
```

---

#### Comprehension/Boolean Slice

```
s[['7.3' in x.split(', ') for x in s.vals]]

         vals
0  7.3, 6.9.1
```

Comment: Notice in one of the rows there is only one entry with no column.  If there is only one value there will be no comma to split on

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  `'6.9'.split(', ')` evaluates to `['6.9']`

Comment: I just noticed that, apparently split() is smart enough to handle single value cases.

Comment: This solution works but I'm going to flag the other as the correct answer only because my original code uses lambda.

Comment: That decision is yours,  but I offered these up because I believe they are better alternatives to using a `lambda` in an `apply`.  Mind you, there isn't much of a difference between my use of `isdisjoint` and `map` but the other two solutions should be preferable for 2 main reasons **1)** `apply` is typically slow and should be avoided. **2)** `lambda` is not as readable.

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of the comma in your string and use: `s[(s["vals"].apply(lambda x: '7.3,' in x))]`

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to a colleague of mine who reminded me about str.split(), similar to @piRSquared's answer, but keeping with the lambda theme.

```
s[s['vals'].str.split(',').apply(lambda x: '7.3' in x)]
```

Comment: This option works perfectly but I agree re:lambdas. I hadn't considered the opportunity to remove these last lambdas from my code.